# Why does it matter where you take moments, when its a lamina?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, moment-of-inertia, moment

I've just been doing moments on laminas for the first time and I think I've missed something crucial.

[image]

If I take moments around point $X$, I get:

**Clockwise**: $30\ \mathrm N$ with a perpendicular distance of $2\ \mathrm m = 60\ \mathrm{Nm}$

**Anti-clockwise**: $10\ \mathrm N$ with a perpendicular distance of $4\ \mathrm m = 40\ \mathrm{Nm}$

So overall moment is clockwise $20\ \mathrm{Nm}$

But then if I take moments around point Y (where the $10\ \mathrm N$ force is acting), I get:

**Clockwise**: $8\ \mathrm N$ with a perpendicular distance of $4\ \mathrm m = 32\ \mathrm{Nm}$

**Anti-clockwise**: $12\ \mathrm N$ with a perpendicular distance of $3\ \mathrm m = 36\ \mathrm{Nm}$ and $30\ \mathrm{N}$ with a perpendicular distance of $2\ \mathrm m = 60\ \mathrm m$

So overall moment is anticlockwise $64\ \mathrm{Nm}$

Why don't I get the same moment at $X$ as I do at $Y$? What is it about laminas that means moments are different, and which moment is the important one?

Comment: What makes you think the sum of the moments about any point has to be the same?

Comment: When we are looking at a rigid rod it's the case. And also logically, the moments just tell us how much an object is rotating, so if it's rigid, surely it's rotating the same amount everywhere

Answer (score 2):

The sum of the moments about any point does not have to be the same.

Suppose the only force acting on the lamina is the 8N force. Then the sum of the moments about X is zero, but about any other point not on the line of action of the 8N force it is non zero.

Only when the object is in static equilibrium will the sum of the moments about any point be the same and that sum will equal zero. Perhaps that is what you were thinking.

Hope this helps.